# How to change enumerate style in GSM package

Tags: numbering, enumerate, itemize, counters, enumitem

I used GSM LaTeX package of AMS to write a book, in which the enumerate environment gives the result as follows:

(1) If blah blah blah.

(2) Else blah blah blah.

(3) Or blah blah blah....

I want to change it to :

1) If blah blah blah.

2) Else blah blah blah.

3) Or blah blah blah....

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item If blah blah blah
\item Else blah blah blah
\item Or blah blah blah 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing line 7 of your code with `\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the `label` key for the `enumerate`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,label={\arabic*)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item If blah blah blah
  \item Else blah blah blah
  \item Or blah blah blah 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*,\label=\arabic*)}` or all levels will share the same style.